# Why can't I put html buttons in a specific place?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble placing buttons in a specific place, I want to create buttons where the red squares in the image are.

I already created the center ones with a `<div class="center">`

but I wanted a way to place the buttons in any pixel, independent of a div, but I don't know how to do it!!

How do I place the buttons in the position of the red squares, please
[image: where I want to put the other buttons, highlighted in red]

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static\style.css">
</head>
<style>
  .center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
<body style="background-color: #1f1f1f">
  <p style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='imagem.jpg')}}" />
</body>
<div class="center">
  <button style=" font-size: 25px"></button>
  <button style=" font-size: 25px"></button>
  <button style=" font-size: 25px">​</button>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <button style=" font-size: 25px">​</button>
  <button style=" font-size: 25px">​</button>
  <button style=" font-size: 25px">​</button>
  <button style=" font-size: 25px">​</button>
  <button style=" font-size: 25px">​</button>
</div>
<div class="rangeslider">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" class="myslider" id="sliderRange">
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Start with a valid HTML document. Style tags belong in the head, not between tags.
`</body>` belongs just before `</html>`

Comment: then if you really want control over the images, give them display: block and position absolute, then you can move them with top and left

Comment: I don't understand very well, can you give a simple example button, please?